# Juntar dados de 2 planilhas e apontar diferenças

Tags: microsoft-excel

Tenho 2 planilhas excel, uma tem os dados do gerenciamento de projetos de uma empresa fictícia e outra os mesmos dados de uma fábrica também fictícia:

```
PLANILHA 1: Empresa
------------------------------
Projeto História    Data    Esforço
PROJ-1  PJ1-1       jan/15  4
PROJ-1  PJ1-2       jan/15  8
PROJ-1  PJ1-3       jan/15  12
PROJ-1  PJ1-4       jan/15  40
PROJ-2  PJ2-1       jan/15  32
PROJ-2  PJ2-2       fev/15  2
PROJ-2  PJ2-3       fev/15  10
PROJ-4  PJ4-2       mai/15  6

PLANILHA 2: Fábrica
------------------------------
ID Projeto  ID Estoria  Data Início Fab Story Point
PROJ-1      PJ1-1           jan/15              2
PROJ-1      PJ1-2           jan/15              4
PROJ-1      PJ1-3           jan/15              6
PROJ-1      PJ1-4           fev/15              10
PROJ-2      PJ2-1           jan/15              32
PROJ-2      PJ2-2           fev/15              2
PROJ-2      PJ2-3           fev/15              10
PROJ-3      PJ3-1           jun/15              10
```

A partir dessas 2 planilhas eu quero gerar uma terceira contendo os seguintes dados:

```
Projeto | História | Data Empresa | Data Fábrica | Pontuação Empresa | Pontuação Fábrica
```

Meu objetivo com isso é identificar divergências de informações, existem dados cadastrados somente em 1 das 2 planilhas, dados da mesma história mas com data ou pontuação diferente, por exemplo.

O problema é que eu não faço ideia de como e com o quê começar.

Comment: Você considerou o uso da fórmula PROCV? Caso não tenha, posso postar uma resposta exemplificando o uso.

Comment: Olá @cantoni, pode postar a resposta, embora tenha pensado no PROCV não sei de que forma devo aplicá-lo.

Comment: Um dúvida @EduardoSilva, isso vai ser feito uma vez só ou você está procurando uma solução para automatizar esse problema?

Comment: Vai ser feito apenas uma vez, @cantoni.

Comment: @EduardoSilva acredito que a solução do seu problema é mesmo com VBA, mas de qualquer forma, aqui esta uma solução interessante se você tiver paciência para aprendê-la: http://ambienteoffice.com.br/blog/ambientexl/#introducao

Comment: Ok, então vou postar a solução considerando que é apenas uma vez. Existe alguns passos manuais, certamente resolverá o seu problema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esse problema pode ser solucionado de de maneira rápida utilizando a fórmula PROCV, entretanto, para isso, será necessário criar uma coluna adicional que servirá como chave primária dos seus dados. Além disso, um passo adicional utilizando uma tabela dinâmica será necessário de forma a extrair apenas um registro por chave-primária (é uma maneira artensal de fazer um distinct no Excel).

Verificando os dados de exemplo, é possível perceber que um determinado ID Projeto e ID Historia nunca repetem, ou seja, temos aí um caso de chave-primária composta.

Faça o seguinte:

- Crie a 3a planilha (a planilha de resultado) com os campos indicados na pergunta. Nessa planilha inclua um campo chamado CHAVE que será o 1o campo da planilha.
- Em cada uma das planilhas Fabrica e Empresa, crie uma coluna chamada CHAVE, também como a 1a coluna da planilha. Coloque a seguinte formula na 1a celula (A2): =B2&";"&C2
- Criada a fórmula, replique a mesma em toda coluna A. Como pode ser observado, essa coluna é a chave primária que será utilizada no PROCV. A chave primária é a concatenação do PROJETO+";"+ESTORIA (o ; será util mais adiante).
- **Importante**: Como existem projetos que estão na Fabrica, mas não estao na Empresa e vice-versa, será necessário um passo extra, de forma a extrair as chaves que serão colocadas na 3a planilha (a planilha de resultado).
- Para isso, crie uma 4a planilha com apenas uma coluna chamada CHAVE. Volte na planilha Empresa e copie/cole (apenas os valores) todo o conteúdo da coluna CHAVE na 4a planilha. Faço o mesmo para a planilha Fabrica. Obviamente, os dados da Fabrica ficarão depois da Empresa. Portanto, a 4a planilha terá todas as chaves primárias de Empresa e Fabrica.
- Terminado esse passo, crie uma Tabela Dinamica e coloque o campo chave nas Linhas dessa tabela. Note que com esse passo, você terá um distinct das chaves das tabelas Fabrica e Empresa. Copie e cole esse dado das linhas da tabela dinamica na coluna chave da 3a planilha;
- Pronto, agora você tem todas as suas chaves de pesquisa. Basta, portanto, montar o seu PROCV. Nas colunas que são referentes à empresa, o seu PROCV buscará na planilha empresa e vice-versa. A chave de pesquisa do PROCV é o campo CHAVE que está nas 3 planilhas.
- A única pendência fica, portanto, nos campos Projeto e Estoria, já que um PROCV neles não resolverá. Para isso foi concatenado o ";".
- No campo Projeto da 3a planilha coloque a seguinte formula: =ESQUERDA(A2;PROCURAR(";";A2;1)-1)
- no campo Estoria da 3a planilha coloque a seguinte formula: =DIREITA(A2;NÚM.CARACT(A2)-PROCURAR(";";A2;1))
- Os outros campos, como dito acima, são obtidos por PROCV.