# Como gerar uma planilha a partir de outra utilizando VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Possuo a planilha abaixo com as seguintes colunas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de gerar uma segunda planilha com base nas informações acima, obedecendo as seguintes condições:

a) Se `categoria == 'Multimídia > Multilaser'`, `categoria = '1'`

b) Se `categoria == 'Sestini > Meninos'`, `categoria = '2'`

c) As novas colunas geradas serão:

1. Título ⇒ **name(pt-br)**;
2. Categoria ⇒ **categories**;
3. Unidades D. ⇒ **quantity**;
4. Preço ⇒ **price**;
5. Data de criação ⇒ **date_added**.

d) As colunas **Perguntas** e **Estado** não comporão a nova planilha

e) A nova planilha deverá conter alguns campos (**shipping**, **sku** e **model**) que já virão com um valor *default*

1. **model** terá o mesmo valor de **Título**

Resultado desejado (nova planilha):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A minha intenção é automatizar esse processo, tendo em vista que a planilha original é exportada de um outro site no formato .CSV, onde utilizei o [Convertio](https://convertio.co/pt/csv-xlsx/) para gerar o .XLS.

Comment: @cantoni, estive pesquisando e encontrei sua resposta [neste](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/92334/juntar-dados-de-2-planilhas-e-apontar-diferen%C3%A7as) tópico. Conseguiria me auxiliar aqui também?

Comment: Você quer gerar uma nova planilha no mesmo documento ou gerar uma nova pasta de trabalho (arquivo novo)?

Comment: @PedroMVM independente, as duas irão me atender.

Comment: "model terá o mesmo valor de Título", mas na linha 3 do seu resultado esperado está o nome da categoria. Estou fazendo levando o enunciado, mesmo vendo que as colunas A e E conterão o mesmo valor.

Answer (score 2):

Fiz o código abaixo seguindo as boas práticas de programação, usando nomes de variáveis mais apropriados com o uso delas, além de não usar `ActiveCell`, `Offset` e outras coisas do tipo. Espero que prefira assim.

```
Option Explicit
Option Private Module
Sub Principal()

    Dim PlanilhaAtual As Worksheet
    Dim PlanilhaNova As Worksheet

    Set PlanilhaAtual = Worksheets(1)

    GerarPlanilha ("Nova")
    Set PlanilhaNova = Worksheets("Nova")

    Dim UltimaLinha As Long
    UltimaLinha = PlanilhaAtual.Cells.Find("*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

' Copiando os valores para a planilha nova
    Dim Linha As Long
    For Linha = 2 To UltimaLinha
        PlanilhaNova.Cells(Linha, 1).Value = PlanilhaAtual.Cells(Linha, 2).Value
        PlanilhaNova.Cells(Linha, 2).Value = _
            ConverterCategoria(CStr(PlanilhaAtual.Cells(Linha, 1).Value))
        PlanilhaNova.Cells(Linha, 3).Value = "yes"
        PlanilhaNova.Cells(Linha, 4).Value = PlanilhaAtual.Cells(Linha, 4).Value
        PlanilhaNova.Cells(Linha, 5).Value = PlanilhaAtual.Cells(Linha, 2).Value
        PlanilhaNova.Cells(Linha, 6).Value = ""
        PlanilhaNova.Cells(Linha, 7).Value = PlanilhaAtual.Cells(Linha, 6).Value
        PlanilhaNova.Cells(Linha, 8).Value = PlanilhaAtual.Cells(Linha, 7).Value
    Next

End Sub
Sub GerarPlanilha(Nome As String)

    Dim Planilha As Worksheet

' Excluindo planilha existente se houver
    For Each Planilha In Worksheets
        If Planilha.Name = Nome Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            Planilha.Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
    Next

' Criando a planilha nova
    Set Planilha = Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
    Planilha.Name = Nome

' Gerando cabeçalho na planilha nova
    Range("A1").Value = "name(pt-br)"
    Range("B1").Value = "categories"
    Range("C1").Value = "shipping"
    Range("D1").Value = "quantity"
    Range("E1").Value = "model"
    Range("F1").Value = "sku"
    Range("G1").Value = "price"
    Range("H1").Value = "date_added"

End Sub
Function ConverterCategoria(Texto As String) As Long

'  O valor 0 é retornado caso o texto não tenha um valor correspondente
    Select Case Texto
        Case "Multimídia > Multilaser"
            ConverterCategoria = 1
        Case "Sestini > Meninos"
            ConverterCategoria = 2
        Case Else
            ConverterCategoria = 0
    End Select

End Function
```

O código contém uma rotina principal (a que você deverá executar), uma sub-rotina para criar a planilha nova (e apagar, caso exista) e uma função para gerar o valor da categoria.

O uso da função é melhor neste seu caso, já que valores novos podem ser acrescentados, por isso mantive à parte, sem misturar com o restante do código. Também coloquei o retorno 0 para o caso do texto não ser encontrado. Caso você encontrar alguma categoria com valor 0, é preciso ver qual (ou quais) foram as categorias que não estão prevista(s) e acrescentar no código.

Se houver alguma questão sobre o código ou algum trecho que precisa ser melhor explicado, é só perguntar que respondo.

Comment: Olá @PedroMVM, código bem estruturado e sucinto. Contudo, duas ressalvas: a) O uso do Private Module gerou o seguinte erro: `Option Private Module not permitted in an object module`, o que seria? b) O não acréscimo do cabeçalho à nova **Planilha**, ou seja → `Planilha.Range("A1").Value = "name(pt-br)"`, e assim por diante.

Comment: Olá. A opção `Option Private Module` serve para que a função existente no módulo não fique disponível como função de planilha. Você pode comentar ou tirar essa linha, a única diferença é que você pode usar a função `ConverterCategoria` na sua planilha. Mas isso não deve atrapalhar em nada. Com relação ao cabeçalho na planilha nova, ele é criado na sub-rotina `GerarPlanilha`, que verifica se existe uma planilha com aquele nome (apagando nesse caso sem o alerta do Excel) e depois gera uma planilha nova ao final da lista de planilhas. Se precisar, acrescente `Planilha.` antes dos  `Range`.

Answer (score 1):

Luccas,

Não sei quantas linhas serão executadas. Mas eu faria assim.

Uma nova consulta de CSV para exportar os dados do CSV, já quebrando em colunas pelo delimitador. Com isso, sempre que for executar, ele só precisa atualizar essa consulta e vc terá todas as linhas do CSV, que atualiza assim:

```
Sheets("Planilha1").Select
Range("A1").Select
Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```

Após isso, com um código parecido com esse, vc consegue trazer os dados de uma pra outra já no formato desejado.

```
Range("A2").Select
NumeroLinhas = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

Range("A2").Select
For x = 1 To NumeroLinhas
    Range("Planilha3!" + ActiveCell.Address) = ActiveCell.Value
    Range("Planilha3!" + ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Address) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
    Range("Planilha3!" + ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Address) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value
    Range("Planilha3!" + ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Address) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Next
```

Perceba que vc vai colar o valor direto na coluna que precisa apenas deslocando com o **offset**.

Answer (score 1):

Verifica o seguinte código... Falta implementar a lógica de atribuição dos valores das colunas respectivas

```
Sub copyTemplate()

Dim wk As Workbook
Dim fileOriginal As Worksheet
Dim lastRow, i As Integer
Set wk = Workbooks.Add

'adicionar cabeçalho
wk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1) = " name(pt-br)"
wk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 2) = "categories"
wk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 3) = "quantity"
wk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 4) = "price"
wk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 5) = "date_added"
wk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 6) = "shipping"
wk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 7) = "sku"
wk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 8) = "model"

'file original onde estão os dados para ser copiados
'nome do ficheiro original...
'quando executares a macro o ficheiro deve estar a aberto
Set fileOriginal = Workbooks("StackOverflowCopyTest.xlsm").Worksheets("Folha1")
'busca a ultima linha do ficheiro original
lastRow = fileOriginal.Cells(fileOriginal.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
'percorre o ficheiro original e copia para o novo ficheiro
For i = 2 To lastRow
'cria a logica aqui
'Cells(i, 1) -> coluna do name
wk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1) = fileOriginal.Cells(i, 2)

'exemplo -> verificar a primeira coluna se é Multimídia > Multilaser
    If fileOriginal.Cells(i, 1) = "Multimídia > Multilaser" Then
         wk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2) = 1
    Else
        wk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2) = 2
    End If

'cria aqui a logica
'Estrutura do cells .Cells(#LINHA, #Coluna)
wk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3) = fileOriginal.Cells(i, 3)
wk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 4) = fileOriginal.Cells(i, 4)
wk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 5) = fileOriginal.Cells(i, 5)
wk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 6) = fileOriginal.Cells(i, 6)
wk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 7) = fileOriginal.Cells(i, 7)
wk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 8) = fileOriginal.Cells(i, 8)

Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

testei aqui e funcionou, insira um botão na planilha com a macro abaixo. Ele vai gerar outra planilha no mesmo arquivo.

```
Sub geraPlanilha()
    Dim contador As Integer
    Dim planilhaOriginal As Worksheet
    Dim novaPlanilha As Worksheet
    Set planilhaOriginal = Workbooks("teste.xlsm").Worksheets(1)
    Set novaPlanilha = Workbooks("teste.xlsm").Worksheets.Add()

    'adicionar cabeçalho
    novaPlanilha.Cells(1, 1) = "name(pt-br)"
    novaPlanilha.Cells(1, 2) = "categories"
    novaPlanilha.Cells(1, 3) = "shipping"
    novaPlanilha.Cells(1, 4) = "quantity"
    novaPlanilha.Cells(1, 5) = "model"
    novaPlanilha.Cells(1, 6) = "sku"
    novaPlanilha.Cells(1, 7) = "price"
    novaPlanilha.Cells(1, 8) = "date_added"

    contador = 2
    'Faz um loop em todas as linhas em que a primeira coluna estiver preenchida
    Do While planilhaOriginal.Cells(contador, 1) <> ""
        'name(pt-br)
        novaPlanilha.Cells(contador, 1) = planilhaOriginal.Cells(contador, 2)
        'categories
        If planilhaOriginal.Cells(contador, 1) = "Multimídia > Multilaser" Then
             novaPlanilha.Cells(contador, 2) = 1
        Else
            novaPlanilha.Cells(contador, 2) = 2
        End If
        'shipping
        novaPlanilha.Cells(contador, 3) = "yes"
        'quantity
        novaPlanilha.Cells(contador, 4) = planilhaOriginal.Cells(contador, 4)
        'model
        novaPlanilha.Cells(contador, 5) = planilhaOriginal.Cells(contador, 2)
        'sku
        novaPlanilha.Cells(contador, 6) = ""
        'price
        novaPlanilha.Cells(contador, 7) = planilhaOriginal.Cells(contador, 6)
        'date_added
        novaPlanilha.Cells(contador, 8) = planilhaOriginal.Cells(contador, 7)

        contador = contador + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Dá pra melhorar, fazendo com que essas categorias sejam buscadas em outra planilha ao invés de ficar fixo no código, mas aí fica a seu critério.